# Make NSButton a Hyperlink in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I was wondering how to make an NSButton a hyperlink so it opens an external webpage in the user's default browser.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot make an `NSButton` a hyperlink because a hyperlink is an HTML concept while a button is a Cocoa interface component.

But you can use a button's target/action to open a URL programmatically. The action could be a method like:

```
- (IBAction)openSomeURL:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:myURL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also look and feel you want to appear button as hyperlink then remove the border of NSButton and use above two answer code for opening the url.